# Assigning coefficient vector back to features in scikit learn Lasso

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I am running a Lasso in scikit learn on a dataset. Here is how my design matrix(X) looks like:

```
    Year    Country SW  NY.GDP.DEFL.KD.ZG.1 NY.GDP.PCAP.KD.ZG   NY.GDP.DEFL.KD.ZG   NE.IMP.GNFS.ZS  NY.GDP.DISC.CN  FS.AST.PRVT.GD.ZS   FS.AST.DOMS.GD.ZS   NY.GDS.TOTL.ZS  NY.GDP.DISC.KN  NY.GDP.NGAS.RT.ZS   NY.GDP.PETR.RT.ZS   NY.GDP.COAL.RT.ZS   NY.GDP.MINR.RT.ZS   NY.GDP.TOTL.RT.ZS   MS.MIL.XPND.GD.ZS
0   0   0   1   -3576217.383052 -5146876.546040 -3471506.772186 -2633821.885258 -3.680928e+06   91.575314   99.278420   -5670429.600369 -3.785639e+06   -4832744.713442 -5461008.378638 -3366796.16132  -3995059.826515 -5565718.989504 -1691426.387465
1   1   0   1   5.713486    0.563529    4.713486    21.969161   -5.000000e+06   88.625556   92.244479   23.625253   1.309500e+10    1.089173    0.983267    0.00000 1.471053    3.860570    2.057921
2   2   0   1   3.559686    2.640931    2.559686    21.466621   -1.000000e+06   87.785550   93.413707   24.273287   1.558700e+10    1.014641    1.021970    0.00000 1.371797    3.681716    1.925137
3   3   0   1   1.337874    3.811404    0.337874    20.646004   1.000000e+06    84.262083   91.313310   23.840716   1.962200e+10    0.445549    0.412880    0.00000 1.079369    2.178213    1.994438
4   0   1   1   7.638720    9.914861    6.638720    25.640006   -1.305679e+11   129.923249  146.277785  51.979295   -6.818467e+11   0.164374    1.500932    2.37375 2.563449    6.954085    2.079635
```

It has three categorical features in the beginning.

Here is how my Target vector(Y) looks like:

```
0   -0.003094
1   -0.015327
2    0.100617
3    0.067728
4    0.089962
```

Both are currently pandas data frame/Series.

Now I Recode my categorical variables in X using oneHotEncoder of scikit.from

```
sklearn import preprocessing
X_train=preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0,1,2],sparse=False).fit_transform(data_train)
```

This transforms the data to something like this:

```
X_train[0:2]
Out[473]:
array([[  1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
         -3.57621738e+06,  -5.14687655e+06,  -3.47150677e+06,
         -2.63382189e+06,  -3.68092799e+06,   9.15753144e+01,
          9.92784200e+01,  -5.67042960e+06,  -3.78563860e+06,
         -4.83274471e+06,  -5.46100838e+06,  -3.36679616e+06,
         -3.99505983e+06,  -5.56571899e+06,  -1.69142639e+06],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
          5.71348642e+00,   5.63529053e-01,   4.71348642e+00,
          2.19691610e+01,  -5.00000000e+06,   8.86255560e+01,
          9.22444788e+01,   2.36252526e+01,   1.30950000e+10,
          1.08917343e+00,   9.83266854e-01,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.47105308e+00,   3.86057046e+00,   2.05792067e+00]])
```

After this I do missing value imputation:

```
X_imputed=preprocessing.Imputer().fit_transform(X_train) 
X_imputed[0:1]
Out[474]:
array([[       1.        ,        0.        ,        0.        ,
               0.        ,        1.        ,        0.        ,
               0.        ,        0.        ,        0.        ,
               0.        ,        0.        ,        0.        ,
               0.        ,        0.        ,        1.        ,
        -3576217.38305151, -5146876.54603993, -3471506.77218561,
        -2633821.88525845, -3680927.9939174 ,       91.57531444,
              99.27842   , -5670429.60036941, -3785638.6047833 ,
        -4832744.71344225, -5461008.37863762, -3366796.16131972,
        -3995059.82651509, -5565718.98950351, -1691426.3874654 ]])
```

By Now I have started getting confused with the order of variables as after using oneHotencoder my data frame is converted to numpy array and strips the headers. SO I am not sure first 13 columns(which are dummies for three categoricals are what and in which order?.

Secondly, I go ahead and run LassoCV to get the right alpha value of Lasso and corresponding coefficients.

```
from sklearn import linear_model 
lasso=linear_model.LassoCV(max_iter=2000,cv=10,normalize=True)
lasso.fit(X_imputed,Y_train)
```

When I check which alpha value it finally chose using cross validation
it gave this:

```
lasso.alpha_
Out[476]:
4.1303618102099771e-05
```

So am assuming this alpha value is the best one which gives least MSE over all 10 folds.

But now when I try to find the lasso path for all alphas it tried, here is what I get. I am creating a numpy array to store MSE of all 10 fold for each alpha chosen by lasso (100 alphas for 10 folds)

```
scores=np.zeros((100,2))
scores[:,0]=lasso.mse_path_[:,0]
scores[:,1]=np.mean(lasso.mse_path_[:,1:],axis=1)
scr=scores[scores[:,1].argsort()]
```

Since I have sorted my scores matrix in ascending order of MSE for each alpha , I expect the first record to show me the alpha for which the score is min.

```
scr[0]
Out[477]:
array([ 441334.91133953,       0.00739538])
```

But I see the alpha value as totally different from what I got in above step using lasso.alpha_. That was to power of -5 and this is power of +5. Why is that?.

Thirdly, here is my coefficient vector from lasso. How do I know which coefficient is mapped to which feature in my original data set (data_train)?. THis is what I need in the end to get the weights corresponding to each feature from the best chose alpha.

```
lasso.coef_
Out[478]:
array([ 0.02930289,  0.01039652, -0.        , -0.05448752,  0.01310975,
        0.        , -0.03755883,  0.02754805, -0.0498908 , -0.10531218,
       -0.08303772,  0.00465392,  0.        , -0.04597282,  0.        ,
        0.00000003,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
       -0.00101291,  0.00155892,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,
```

Right now because the headers are stripped and all , I have no clue which weights correspond to which feature. Also, why the alpha value is different when I choose lasso.alpha_ or when I do lasso_mse_path_ and check the lowest mse.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

To relate the feature indices back to the original feature columns, you can use the `feature_indices_` attribute of `OneHotEncoder` after fitting:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
encoder = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0,1,2])
X_train = encoder.fit_transform(data_train)
print encoder.feature_indices_
```

Output:

```
[0 4 6 8]
```

According to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html):

> feature_indices_ : array of shape (n_features,)
>   Indices to feature ranges. Feature i in the original data is mapped to features from feature_indices_[i] to feature_indices_[i+1] (and then potentially masked by active_features_ afterwards)

In this case, the first 4 dimensions in the one-hot encoded space correspond to column `Year`, the next 2 correspond to column `Country` and the last 2 correspond to `SW`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. Just wanted to check something on this. So when I use OneHotEncoder, then are you saying using the feature_indices all the encoded features are mapped back to original ones. Like if first column above is transformed into 4 columns, then it says which column were transformed right?. But that doesn't solve my problem. My problem is, if I run an algo using scikit learn, after encoding in hot encoder space, then it gives me some coefficients values for the model. How do I relate which coefficient value is for which original feature.

Comment: Like if I have a categorical variable with 3 categories. Then it creates three dummies? Shouldn't it create two dummies and absence of all is indicative of third category? And secondly, I am getting like some coefficient for each dummy. Technically in my final model I would want to have that original single variable with one coefficient. How do I get that single coefficient for the final model for the original variable